# Get the index of the selected radio buttons

Tags: c++, mfc, radio-button

I have 4 radio buttons on my dialog and all are under one group.

In order to group them i have set the group option to TRUE for the first radio button and  FALSE for the rest of them.

I have given the tab order accordingly.

As i grouped them together, i can only create one member variable for the entire group lets say it is m_RadioGroup.

I have "Ok" button on my dialog. Now on click of OK button i wanted to know which radio button is selected out of 4 of them.

How do we achieve this?

Comment: I could do this by adding a variable of type value to the group.I returns me the index

Comment: m_RadioGroup is int or CButton?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use only 1 variable for 4 item.

Every item should have its own variable. Then witch a switch-case or something else find the radio button selected.